# separate splines into multiple splines

Tags: animation-nodes

From an spline I'm getting a bunch of evenly distributed points between the control points of that same spline using the evaluate spline node. Now I want to create new splines dividing the original spline using the obtained points. The image below shows the desired outcome:
[image]

How can this be done using animation nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a float list representing the parameters of the points we want to split at. We can compute a list with the last element removed and a list with the first element removed and use those lists as the start and end list of a trim node respectively as follows:

[image: Node Tree]